# Model.find().toArray() claiming to not have .toArray() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug, passport.js

I am very new to Node.js and MongoDB and am trying to piece together my own blogging application. I have a problem trying to query through my 'Blog' model for ones with a specific username. When I try to run:

```
var userBlogs = function(username) {
  ub = Blog.find({author: username}).toArray();
  ub = ub.reverse();
};
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Query> has no method 'toArray'
```

I know globals are bad but I've just been trying to get it to work. The Mongo documentation claims that a cursor is returned which can have the `toArray()` method called on it. I have no idea why it won't work.

Here is my schema/model creation:

```
var blogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type:String, required: true},
  author: String,
  content: {type:String, required: true},
  timestamp: String
});
var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

Here are the /login and /readblog requests

```
app.get('/readblog', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.render('readblog', {user: req.user, blogs: ub})
})

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { user: req.user, message: req.session.messages });
});

app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login'}),
  function(req, res) {
    userBlogs(req.user.username);
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

The end result is supposed to work with this Jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    if blogs
        for blog in blogs
            h2= blog[title]
            h4= blog[author]
            p= blog[content]
            h4= blog[timestamp]
    a(href="/writeblog") Write a new blog
```

How can I get the query to output an array, or even work as an object?

Comment: should add 'mongoose' to your tags

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `toArray` function exists on the `Cursor` class from the Native MongoDB NodeJS driver ([reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray)). The `find` method in MongooseJS returns a `Query` object ([reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Query)). There are a few ways you can do searches and return results.

As there are no synchronous calls in the NodeJS driver for MongoDB, you'll need to use an asynchronous pattern in all cases. Examples for MongoDB, which are often in JavaScript using the MongoDB Console imply that the native driver also supports similar functionality, which it does not.

```
var userBlogs = function(username, callback) {
    Blog.find().where("author", username).
          exec(function(err, blogs) {
             // docs contains an array of MongooseJS Documents
             // so you can return that...
             // reverse does an in-place modification, so there's no reason
             // to assign to something else ...
             blogs.reverse();
             callback(err, blogs);
          });
};
```

Then, to call it:

```
userBlogs(req.user.username, function(err, blogs) {
    if (err) { 
       /* panic! there was an error fetching the list of blogs */
       return;
    }
    // do something with the blogs here ...
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

You could also do sorting on a field (like a blog post date for example):

```
Blog.find().where("author", username).
   sort("-postDate").exec(/* your callback function */);
```

The above code would sort in descending order based on a field called `postDate` (alternate syntax: `sort({ postDate: -1})`.

Comment: That sorting is exactly what I need. I'm assuming 'postDate' is just a new Date() Object that's connected to the blog? Much like my 'timestamp', or do you recommend I change the Date(?) output?

Comment: Yes, I was imagining that it was a `Date`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Blog.find({}).lean().exec(function (err, blogs) {
  // ... do something awesome... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should utilize the callback of find:

```
var userBlogs = function(username, next) {
    Blog.find({author: username}, function(err, blogs) {
        if (err) {
            ...
        } else {
            next(blogs)
        }
    })
}
```

Now you can get your blogs calling this function:

```
userBlogs(username, function(blogs) {
   ...
})
```

Comment: @WiredPrairie did this help any?