# Remove multiple documents from array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My document contains an array like:

```js
{
    "differentialDiagnosis" : "IART/Flutter",
    "explanation" : "The rhythm.",
    "fileName" : "A115a JPEG.jpg",
    "history" : "1 year old with fussiness",
    "interpretationList" : [ 
        {
           "interpretations" : [
                ObjectId("54efe7c8d6d5ca3d5c580a22"), 
                ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "interpretations" : [ 
                ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26"), 
                ObjectId("54efe82ad6d5ca3d5c580a28")
             ]
        }
    ],
}
```

and I want to remove all occurrences of `ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26")`,
but I write a query:

```js
db.ekgs.update({'interpretationList.interpretations':ObjectId("54c09fb3581c4c8c218d1a40")}, {$pull:{ 'interpretationList.$.interpretations':{ ObjectId("54c09fb3581c4c8c218d1a40")}})
```

This **removes only first occurrence** of `ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26")`.

Comment: That is not a valid document structure that is possible under MongoDB or JSON or BSON.

Comment: Can this is possible in this type of schema?
If yes, Can you suggest?

Comment: This stems from basic JSON notation. Right after "explanation" cannot possibly be a sub-document without a "key" name.If you want to ask a question then we at least ask that you ask something valid.

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake,I corrected this.

Comment: If any body have any suggestion please help.I am working on this from past 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query is only removing the first occurrence is because, as explained in [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in the documentation, "the positional `$` operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document".

The problem is that it is really tricky to deal with these types of updates with schema having embedded arrays in embedded objects in embedded arrays. In order to get around this problem, if you are able to flatten the schema, then your update becomes much easier. So if instead, your document looked like this:

```js
{
    "differentialDiagnosis" : "IART/Flutter",
    "explanation" : "The rhythm.",
    "fileName" : "A115a JPEG.jpg",
    "history" : "1 year old with fussiness",
    "interpretations" : [
        ObjectId("54efe7c8d6d5ca3d5c580a22"), 
        ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26"),
        ObjectId("54efe82ad6d5ca3d5c580a28")
    ]
}
```

Then your query would be as simple as the one below. (Remember to add `{ "multi": true }` as an option if you want to update multiple documents).

```js
db.ekgs.update(
    { "interpretations": ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26")},
    { "$pull": { "interpretations": ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26") }}
);
```

But I understand that you might not be able to change the schema. In that case, you can try a solution that requires a small script. In the `mongo` shell, you can use the following bit of JavaScript to do the operation.

```js
// Get cursor with documents requiring updating.
var oid = ObjectId("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26");
var c = db.ekgs.find({ "interpretationList.interpretations": oid });

// Iterate through cursor, removing oid from each subdocument in interpretationList.
while (c.hasNext()) {
    var isModified = false;
    var doc = c.next(); 
    var il = doc.interpretationList;
    for (var i in il) {
        var j = il[i].interpretations.length;
        while (j--) {

            // If oid to remove is present, remove it from array
            // and set flag that the document has been modified.
            if (il[i].interpretations[j].str === oid.str) {
                il[i].interpretations.splice(j, 1);
                isModified = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // If modified, update interpretationList for document.
    if (isModified) {
        db.ekgs.update({ "_id": doc._id }, { "$set": { "interpretationList": il }});
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Example of how it might work using the Node.js driver.

```js
// Get cursor with documents requiring updating.
var oid = new ObjectID("54efe80bd6d5ca3d5c580a26");
var ekgs = db.collection("ekgs");
ekgs.find({ "interpretationList.interpretations": oid },
          function(err, c) {    

    if(err) throw err;

    // Iterate through cursor, removing oid from each subdocument in interpretationList.
    c.each(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // If doc is null then the cursor is exhausted/empty and closed.
        if (doc != null) {
            var isModified = false;         
            var il = doc.interpretationList;
            for (var i in il) {
                var j = il[i].interpretations.length;
                while (j--) {

                    // If oid to remove is present, remove it from array
                    // and set flag that the document has been modified.
                    if (il[i].interpretations[j].equals(oid)) {                         
                        il[i].interpretations.splice(j, 1);
                        isModified = true;
                    }
                }
            }           

            // If modified, update interpretationList for document.
            if (isModified) {
                ekgs.update({ "_id": doc._id },
                            { "$set": { "interpretationList": il }},
                            function(err, res) {

                    if (err) throw err;

                    // Callback.
                    console.log(res);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is it good ?
i think it is  effect our service response time.
it is not working in mongo shell.it through error.

Comment: c is undefined.
how can i query it from nodeJs.

Comment: I see. The thing is, in the `mongo` shell you can assign the return value of `db.collection.find()` to a variable. Hence the line: `var c = db.ekgs.find({ "interpretationList.interpretations": oid });` In Node.js you need to do this as a callback, let me add it to my answer.

Comment: @grishabh, I added the sample Node.js code. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Are you using the MongoDB native Node.js driver?

Comment: The find method in MongooseJS returns a Query object (reference).And to apply each method we need to array.
In mongoose there is no toArray method.
Here Is the reference to return array form find query in mongoose 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method

Comment: Yes, Mongoose is different, but you can adapt the code quite easily to follow a pattern similar to `Model.find({ 'some.value': 5 }, function (err, docs) { // docs is an array already });` Then you just need to change the `c` to `docs` and the `c.each()` to a loop that goes through the elements in `docs`. Does that make sense? More info [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html).

Comment: In this case i am find same error, doc doesn't have any method each.

Comment: `docs` will then be an array, which you can traverse like you traverse any array. You can replace `each()` with `for (doc in docs) { // Put what is in each() here }`.