# find(...).populate is not a function in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate two tables in mongoose and node and I receive the error that populate is not a function.

I have search and in the documentation it seems that it does the same as I.

Here the model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dodleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    productorId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Productor"},
    description: String,
    ambassadorId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Ambassador"},
    accepted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    read: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    deliveryAddress: {
        lat: String,
        lng: String
    },
    createdAt: Date,
    products: [
        {
            primaryImage: String,
            images: [],
            name: String,
            max: Number,
            min: Number,
            step: Number,
            stock: Number,
            normalPrice: Number,
            doodlePrice: Number,
            freeShipping: Boolean,
            freeShippingFrom: Number
        }
    ],
    endsAt: Date,
    packagingType: String,
    orders: [
        {
            name: String,
            email: String,
            purchases: [
                {
                    productId: String,
                    quantity: Number
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Doodle', dodleSchema);
```

And then the find that I use:

```
router.route('/requests/:id')
.get(function (req, res) {
    doodleCollection
        .find({
            ambassadorId: new mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.id),
            read: false
        })
        .populate('productorId')
        .toArray(function (error, results) {
            if (error) {
                res.json({'error': "Ha habido un error en la extracción de requests"});
                return false;
            }

            var alertNew = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].read == false) {
                    readed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            res.json({
                requests: results,
                alertNew: alertNew
            });
    });
});
```

This is the error that I get:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pDJN.png)

Comment: you can try changing the line about the ambassador id to `{ ambassadorId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }`

Comment: also, `toArray` is not part of Mongoose (you can reference the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method). Try removing `toArray()` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution and was pretty easy. Seemed that I was really close yesterday.

I was doing the populate method in a collection `doodleCollection` and I needed to do it in the model.

Changing the object that makes the find totally worked.

Instead of `doodleCollection.find(...)` now I call `doodleModel.find(...)` and populate is working perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I was using following which gives me null as data:-

```
let PostModel = mongoose.model('Post');
```

Then I changed it as following and populate method worked:-

```
let PostModel = require("../model/post.js"); //path to your post model
```

Make sure you exported Model from your post.js model file like following:-

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```