# Get data from mongoDB and Nodejs: toArray is not a function error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
var user = User.find({}).limit(1).skip(10).toArray();
```

but I get the error saying `toArray` is not a function.

But if I do following I am getting all the records:

```
User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(users);
    });
```

I am using mongoose package for the purpose.

What am I missing here or doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you check it on 'mongo cell'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose is one layer on top mongodb, it cover almost all mongodb query/command but not all and few of them might behave in a slightly different way in mongoose. In case of toArray(), mongoose.find() return a query object, not a cursor. toArray() is only available for cursor

[Model.find().toArray() claiming to not have .toArray() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method)

Answer (score 0):

> The `toArray` function exists on the `Cursor class` from the `Native MongoDB NodeJS driver` check reference [node-mongodb-native](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray)

If you are using `mongoose` then you can convert it in your callback function