# .aggregate(...).toArray is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

here is the code I am getting the error on.
I have tried multiple ways but keet getting the same error.
TypeError: _user10.default.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function
I searched for other answers but they are mongodb not mongoose
ex  db.collection('users').aggregate
any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
import User from './user.model';
import socket from './../../CHATtest/web/socket.js';



getUserInfo({userId,socketId = false}){
    let queryProjection = null;
    if(socketId){
        queryProjection = {
            "socketId" : true
        }
    } else {
        queryProjection = {
            "username" : true,
            "online" : true,
            '_id': false,
            'id': '$_id'
        }
    }
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
    //const result = await User.aggregate([{
    //await User.aggregate([{
    User.aggregate([{
    //DB.collection('users').aggregate([{
                $match:  {
                    _id : userId
                }
            },{
                $project : queryProjection
            }
  ]).toArray( (err, result) => {
                if( err ){
                    reject(err);
                }
                socketId ? resolve(result[0]['socketId']) : resolve(result);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Will User.aggregate return a cursor? toArray is only available on a cursor: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/

Comment: well I know that .aggregate always returns Objects but that does not mean you cannot put them in an array and return the array in an object.  Maybe I am not understanding the question.   I am a newbie with this

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381453/get-data-from-mongodb-and-nodejs-toarray-is-not-a-function-error... Which simply says mongoose doesn't have `.toArray()` cursor method

Answer (score 1):

Per the Mongoose documentation, calling Model.aggregate() returns an Aggregate object (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate). It does not have a toArray() method, which is why you're getting the error.

The Aggregate object is chainable,and you need to end the chain with a call to exec(). That will return a promise (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)

Comment: `.aggregate(...).exec is not a function` if I change to .exe(), I still get this error :') what can I do ?