# Sorting MongoDB result by another MongoDB result is returning [null, null, null]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting

I'm performing two MongoDB queries, and then I want to synchronize the resulting arrays, to make sure they are in the same order.

The first array is a set of (20) questions ids (this is the correct order):

```json
q_id_arr: [
   "5f86da2d37e3d200040ba523",
   "5f86b6ce37e3d200040ba4c6",
   "5ffc4abea04f3c0004e46cf3",
   "5f86b66537e3d200040ba4c5",
   "5f87f368554f370004ed17b4",
   "5f86e48c37e3d200040ba53c",
   "5ffc4dc4a04f3c0004e46d0b",
   "5f86e19037e3d200040ba534",
   "5f86aaa237e3d200040ba49b",
   "5ffc479ba04f3c0004e46ce0",
   "5f86b9dc37e3d200040ba4d2",
   "5f85828e0e1bd30004361430",
   "5f8700c937e3d200040ba548",
   "5f86d81737e3d200040ba51c",
   "5f8708d237e3d200040ba568",
   "5f87060d37e3d200040ba55c",
   "5f857dac0e1bd3000436141c",
   "5f85703e0e1bd300043613ec",
   "5f87e9d4554f370004ed178e",
   "5f8073c04ad88e00041f015f"
]
```

The second array is a set of (20) results associated with the question ids:

```json
team_trends: [
   {
      "_id":"5f87e9d4554f370004ed178e",
      "positive":0.93,
      "engaged":0.558
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86e19037e3d200040ba534",
      "positive":0.585,
      "engaged":0.567
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f85828e0e1bd30004361430",
      "positive":0.7,
      "engaged":0.666
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f8073c04ad88e00041f015f",
      "positive":0.31,
      "engaged":0.30999999999999994
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f87f368554f370004ed17b4",
      "positive":0.5449999999999999,
      "engaged":0.57
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86b6ce37e3d200040ba4c6",
      "positive":0.855,
      "engaged":0.46599999999999997
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f857dac0e1bd3000436141c",
      "positive":0.92,
      "engaged":0.524
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f85703e0e1bd300043613ec",
      "positive":0.15,
      "engaged":0.39
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86aaa237e3d200040ba49b",
      "positive":0.15000000000000002,
      "engaged":0.584
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86b66537e3d200040ba4c5",
      "positive":0.37,
      "engaged":0.386
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86e48c37e3d200040ba53c",
      "positive":0.615,
      "engaged":0.548
   },
   {
      "_id":"5ffc479ba04f3c0004e46ce0",
      "positive":0.42000000000000004,
      "engaged":0.583
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86b9dc37e3d200040ba4d2",
      "positive":0.68,
      "engaged":0.662
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86d81737e3d200040ba51c",
      "positive":0.03,
      "engaged":0.516
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f87060d37e3d200040ba55c",
      "positive":0.14,
      "engaged":0.454
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f86da2d37e3d200040ba523",
      "positive":0.47,
      "engaged":0.41500000000000004
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f8708d237e3d200040ba568",
      "positive":0.17,
      "engaged":0.76
   },
   {
      "_id":"5ffc4dc4a04f3c0004e46d0b",
      "positive":0.395,
      "engaged":0.53
   },
   {
      "_id":"5ffc4abea04f3c0004e46cf3",
      "positive":0.365,
      "engaged":0.679
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f8700c937e3d200040ba548",
      "positive":0.93,
      "engaged":0.6980000000000001
   }
]
```

I want to reorganize `team_trends` into the same order as `q_id_arr`

Here is the code I'm using (following [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538509/sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-of-ids)):

```
let c = [];
q_id_arr.forEach((q_oid => c.push(team_trends.find((obj => obj._id == q_oid)))));
```

However when I print `console.log("the result of c"+ c)` I get this result:

```
the result of c: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

Is this the right approach? Any suggestions are appreciated!

**More Details:**

Before this step I acquired the `q_id_arr` through mapping over an `aggregate` result, like this:

`let q_id_arr = await user_trends.map(({ question_oid }) => question_oid)`

When I tested `console.log(typeof q_id_arr)` it returned `object`.

How can I sort through the object??

Comment: Please note -- I did try sorting with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId( )` but it made no difference

Comment: Can you try this code: 
`q_id_arr.forEach((q_oid => c.push(team_trends.find((obj => obj._id.equals(q_oid))))));`
I tried your code by copy-pasting the exact arrays and your code seems to be working fine. This means there is some other issue than code logic.

@izzi

Comment: Thanks @ShabbirAhmad - I think the issue is the step before this, because I created the arrays by using a map function: `let q_id_arr = await user_trends.map(({ question_oid }) => question_oid)`

Comment: even if you created arrays by using the map function, your code should work. The issue seems to be that the two values you are comparing are of different type hence no element in the array is returned by the find function. @izzi

Comment: _"Before this step I acquired the q_id_arr through mapping over an aggregate result, like this:""_: Aggregate results do not return array, it returns a _cursor_. What did the aggregate result print?

Comment: `typeof` returned `object`, and the console.log returned: `[{"positive":0.84,"question_oid":"5f86da2d37e3d200040ba523"
,"created_date":"2021-09-20T07:23:41.316Z","engaged":0.368},{"positive":0.96,"qu
estion_oid":"5f86b6ce37e3d200040ba4c6","created_date":"2021-09-20T07:23:05.860Z"
,"engaged":0.504},...]`

Comment: Do a `toArray()` to the end of aggregate query. Then you will get an array.

Comment: I tried and the result: `TypeError: user_trends.toArray is not a function`

Comment: The syntax needs to be like this: `let agg_arr_result = db.collection.aggregate([ .... ]).toArray()`. This works in `mongo` shell. If you are working with MongoDB NodeJS Driver, the syntax can different - check the API documentation.

Comment: I tried it exactly like that, result: `TypeError: Answer.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function`

Comment: `toArray()`, _not_ `toArray`

Comment: the code is exactly as you said. I did use `toArray()`, but the TypeError does not show the `()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028101/aggregate-toarray-is-not-a-function

Comment: Where is your code run from? Is it from the `mongo` shell? Or are you using a NodeJS driver?

Comment: @Izzi
If you are using mongoose then it already returns an array from the aggregate function. I still think the issue is in your comparison.
Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/comparing-mongoose-id-and-strings

Comment: I tried this comparison: `user_trends.forEach((user => c.push(q_id_arr.find((obj => obj._id.toString() == user.question_oid.toString())))));` and it matched, but all it is putting into the `c` array is the _id, and I want the whole object

Comment: @Izzi use this
`user_trends.forEach((user => c.push(team_trends.find((obj => obj._id.toString() === user.question_oid.toString())))));`

Comment: That was it... Long road to success. Thank you both for the help -- if either of you wish to type this up as an answer and explain the issue, I will accept! Thanks again!

Comment: @Izzi awesome. let me type it up as an answer.

Comment: @Izzi I have typed it as an answer. Kindly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final code that fixed the issue.

```
user_trends.forEach((user => c.push(team_trends.find((obj => obj._id.toString() === user.question_oid.toString())))));
```

A couple of points to note here:

1. If you are using mongoose then it already returns an array from the aggregate function.
2. Mongoose uses the MongoDB NodeJs native driver at its core. In core driver ObjectId has a function `.equals(otherId)`. It is always best to use this function for id comparisons.

References:

1. [Comparing mongoose _id and strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/comparing-mongoose-id-and-strings)
2. [.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028101/aggregate-toarray-is-not-a-function)
3. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals

Comment: Although the id's all appeared the same in console, they were in fact different. Standardizing variable types (ie: `toString()`) should be a go-to trouble-shooting technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using the arrays `map` method:

```
let sorted_team_trends = q_id_arr.map( q => team_trends.find(t => t._id === q) );
```

Assuming the two arrays are defined as fields like this:

```
let q_id_arr = [
        "5f86da2d37e3d200040ba523",
        "5f86b6ce37e3d200040ba4c6",
        "5ffc4abea04f3c0004e46cf3",
        ...
];

let team_trends = [
        {
                "_id" : "5f87e9d4554f370004ed178e",
                "positive" : 0.93,
                "engaged" : 0.558
        },
        {
                "_id" : "5f86e19037e3d200040ba534",
                "positive" : 0.585,
                "engaged" : 0.567
        },
        ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I just tried and the result is also `[null, null, null,...]`

Comment: I tried with the two arrays (as two JavaScript array fields) you had posted in your question as two array fields; and I get the sorted result correctly. Are the two arrays defined as variables? Or documents? What is the source of the two arrays?

Comment: Ok, I think you are onto the issue... Before this step, I used a map function to create the `q_id_arr` and when I tried `typeof q_id_arr` it is returning `object`

Comment: See the edited answer with sample input I had used from your question post.

Comment: Yes, your code works, but not in my case, because I created the array like this: `let q_id_arr = await user_trends.map(({ question_oid }) => question_oid)`

Comment: What is `user_trends` ?

Comment: `user_trends` is the same as `team_trends`, just for a single user. What I did was grab the results for the user, and then try to find the same results from the team, but the team results returned in different order, so now I'm trying to re-align them.