# Mongoose toArray() undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Whats the difference when doing a connection through mongo and through mongoose? Because this code is able to find my document.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mymongourl", 
function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    return console.dir(err);
  }

  var asset = db.collection('assets');
  asset.find({
    name: 'John'
  }).toArray(function (err, items) {
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```

But this code give me 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined'

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   mongoose.connect('mymongourl');
   var db = mongoose.connection;

  var asset = db.collection('assets');
  asset.find({
    name: 'John'
  }).toArray(function (err, items) {
    console.log(items);
  });
```

Comment: Mongoose does not have a `.toArray()` method. In fact it does not even have a "cursor" method really, but instead just uses a plain node "stream" if you ask it to. By default mongoose instead "transforms" the results of a `.find()` query to "an array" for you. So there is not even any need to call such a method using mongoose.

Comment: then i get undefined error

Comment: [`.find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) either takes a callback as in `.find({ name: 'John' },function(err,items) {` or you call [`.exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) with the callback ``.find({ name: 'John' }),exec(function(err,items) {` [All covered in the duplicate question answers **which you should be reading**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method). Also covered in the documentation of mongoose which I have linked to. Read both.