# How to make an array of all the values inside a collection with mongodb (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I keep getting promise pending.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true } , function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    var gr = dbo.collection("collectionname").distinct("name");

    // var everyrecord = dbo.collection("collectionname").find({}).toArray();

    console.log(gr);

    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true } , function(err, db) {

if (err) throw err;

var dbo = db.db("mydb");

 var gr = dbo.collection("collectionname").distinct("name");
 gr = gr.toArray();

// var everyrecord = dbo.collection("collectionname").find({}).toArray();

  console.log(gr);

  db.close();
});
```

Comment: There is no *toArray* method on *Promises*. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method

Answer (score 1):

If you make the function *async*, you can just *await* the result:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true } , async function(err, db) {
    // ...

    var gr = await dbo.collection("collectionname").distinct("name");
    console.log(gr);

    // ...
});
```

Comment: @f.pythonlover Any reason the other (non working) answer is marked as solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using .toArray(),

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true } , function(err, db) {

      if (err) throw err;

      db.collection("collectionname").distinct("name").toArray(function (error, response) {
         console.log(error);
         console.log(response);
      });
    });
```

Comment: MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true } , function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("mydb");
      dbo.collection("collectionname").distinct("name").toArray(function (error, response) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(response);
      });

});  this didn t work? what am i missing?

Comment: it says that toarray is not a function

Comment: You're not missing anything. There is no *toArray* method for promises. Have a look at my async/await suggestion - assuming your node version supports it.