# no result with mongoose .find() when looking into array of a single document

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I know it's me improperly formatting the query but i cannot seem to get entries in a document from a nested array. What i am attempting to do is retrieve all of the objects in the array with a specific value in the menu field.

I am also using [mongo-tenant](https://github.com/craftup/node-mongo-tenant) so the Settings object is already limited to a single document within the collection as it's the only document in settings for that tenant. (req.params.db is referenced earlier in the url than the visible route)

so far i have tried, based on many googlings

`.find({}) // returns entire object as below`

`.find({dropsDowns: { menu: { $eq: req.params.menu }}}) // returns []`

`.find({ dropsDowns: { menu: req.params.menu } }) // returns []`

`.find({'dropDowns.menu':req.params.menu}) // returns entire object`

`.find({ ['dropDowns.menu']: req.params.menu }) // returns entire object`

I also tried to do a few forms of the aggregation methods with less than ideal results as that assumes i actually know how to find the right stuff to aggregate, which i obviously do not.

```
settingsRoute.route('/dropDowns/:menu').get(function(req, res) {
  const Settings = baseSettings.byTenant(req.params.db)
  Settings.find({}).exec(function(
    err,
    menu
  ) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err)
    }
    res.status(200).json(menu)
  })
})
```

this returns the below to my browser

```
[
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be2699",
dropDowns: [
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be26a7",
menu: "frequencyOptions",
text: "Monthly",
value: 30,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z"
},
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be26a6",
menu: "frequencyOptions",
text: "Every two months",
value: 60,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z"
},
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be26a3",
menu: "meterIntervals",
text: "250",
value: 250,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z"
},
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be26a2",
menu: "meterIntervals",
text: "500",
value: 500,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z"
},
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be269e",
menu: "transitionIntervals",
text: "Due at normal interval",
value: 0,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z"
},
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be269d",
menu: "transitionIntervals",
text: "Offset by 25% of normal",
value: 250,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.287Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.287Z"
}
],
tenantId: "maxx1",
siteSettings: {
siteTheme: "dark",
friendlyName: "No Name Set :(",
activeStatus: "transit",
previousStatus: "transit",
numBackupsToKeep: 10,
daysPerBackup: 7,
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be26ad",
backups: [ ],
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.287Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.287Z"
},
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.287Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.287Z",
__v: 0
}
]
```

What is the proper formatting to only have something like the below return if i were to hit the api with `/dropDowns/frequencyOptions`

```
dropDowns: [
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be26a7",
menu: "frequencyOptions",
text: "Monthly",
value: 30,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z"
},
{
_id: "5cea1b835e13fb4180be26a6",
menu: "frequencyOptions",
text: "Every two months",
value: 60,
tenantId: "maxx1",
createdAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z",
updatedAt: "2019-05-26T04:52:19.286Z"
},
}
```

I am still building the structure of the database so if there is a more efficient way to go about getting this kind of data together then i am open to recommendations as well.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo doc is pretty well done: [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

find method returns a cursor. You need to call .toArray() to turn cursor as a json array.
You may use pagination if there is a lot of result, like with skip/limit.

For the rest model, I would return directly the array of dropDowns, no need to embed it in an object with a dropDowns property.

Comment: I wouldn't be here if i hadn't read the doc's. Many times over. In the end what i want to be able to do is have the items presorted within only the context of their individual menu options as some with sort by value and others will sort by text.

Comment: thhis is using mongoose find which is different than the described cursor acording to this post unless that has changed since this reference is a bit aged. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859457/8551436

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a new collection just for the dropdown options, the tenant will sort them appropriatly for that page and i can then fo a direct sort with `.find({name:req.param.name})` to toArray's needed. Maybe later when i have gained more knowledge about how to handle the returns i will revisit pulling and parsing the array as needed.