# How to use Model.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).toArray(function(error,result)?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create and end point using node.js and MongoDB and running into the error below,any idea how to fix it?

I am new to this and tried to looked at [Model.find().toArray() claiming to not have .toArray() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method/20859457#20859457) but couldn't really figure what the solution is, any idea how to fix this?

```
const Wifi_gerrit_commit_messages = require("./models/wifi_gerrit_commit_messages");

app.get("/api/wifi_gerrit_commit_messages", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.params)
  Wifi_gerrit_commit_messages.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).toArray(function(error,result){
    if(error){
      return response.status(500).send(error);
    }
    response.send(result);
    });

  });
```

Error:-

```
TypeError: Wifi_gerrit_commit_messages.find(...).sort(...).toArray is not a function
    at /Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/backend/app.js:456:57
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/backend/app.js:101:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/wifiroots/app-be/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

UPDATE:-

```
app.get("/api/wifi_gerrit_commit_messages", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.params)
  Wifi_gerrit_commit_messages.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}),function(error,result){
    if(error){
      return response.status(500).send(error);
    }
    response.send(result);
    };

  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model.find().toArray() claiming to not have .toArray() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method)

Comment: @turivishal - I couldn't figure how to use that,I already mentioned that in my question

Comment: Mongoose does not have a `.toArray()` method. By default mongoose instead "transforms" the results of a .find() query to "an array" for you. So there is not even any need to call such a method using mongoose.

Comment: @turivishal - I updated on what I tried without the .toArray(),the error is gone but calling `http://localhost:3000/api/wifi_gerrit_commit_messages` it just hungs and no output,what am I missing here?

Comment: nvm,I got it to work and posted an answer,LMK if there is a better error handling way

Answer (score -1):

Following worked

```
app.get("/api/wifi_gerrit_commit_messages", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.params)
  Wifi_gerrit_commit_messages.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).exec(function(error,result){
    if(error){
      return response.status(500).send(error);
    }
    res.send(result);
    });

  });
```